# Multiple Fragment in an activity

Tags: android

I'm using multiple fragments in an navigation drawer activity and at end of flow ,on my last fragment I call/start another activity.so on the new activity I have onOptionsItemselect() function on action bar to take u back to previous activity.
it take me to my navigation drawer activity with the first fragment in it .
but my question **how to bring last or random fragment when I click the onOptionsItemselect() on actionbar?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle it in your application logic.

**action bar to take u back to previous activity**

If you are handling with explicit intent then you will have to add an extra and receive it in your navigation drawer activity.

If you are handling by finish(),It will go back to previous state of the activity.

Comment: Which way are you going back to previous activity ? StartActivity(intent) or finish()

Comment: startActivity(intent)

Comment: Then you can start activity with exIra saying "what_to_opem" with value and in activity receive it and depending on this value take action